# Rounding a Decimal number in Elixir

Tags: decimal, elixir

I have this Decimal number Elixir:

```
c1 = Decimal.div(a1, b1)
# => #Decimal<0.006453859622556080696687234694>
```

How can I round it to a shorter number with a smaller number of digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Like this: `Decimal.new(".006453859622556080696687234694") |> Decimal.round(5) #=> #Decimal<0.00645>`?

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/readme.html#examples

Answer (score 5):

As @Dogbert said in comment - the easiest way to just `round` a number:

```
iex> alias Decimal, as: D
nil
iex> d = D.div(D.new(1), D.new(3))
#Decimal<0.3333333333333333333333333333>
iex> D.round(d, 5)
#Decimal<0.33333>
```

**EDIT:**

Below is not entirely true!! Precision is number of digits in coefficient of decimal, not the actual rounding of number. So if you set Precision to 5 and then you make some calculations on the numbers you will only get numbers with total number of digits in coefficient equal to 5. For instance:

```
iex> D.set_context(%D.Context{D.get_context | precision: 5})
:ok
iex> a = D.div(D.new(100.12345), D.new(3))
#Decimal<33.374>
```

I'm really sorry for totally wrong info!!

> But if you expect every operation to be rounded then you can set
>   `Context` first and after setting it, `Decimal` will use the newly set
>   precision on every operation.
>
> ```
> iex> D.set_context(%D.Context{D.get_context | precision: 5})
> :ok
> iex> a = D.div(D.new(1), D.new(3))
> #Decimal<0.33333>
> iex> b = D.new("0.006453859622556080696687234694")
> #Decimal<0.006453859622556080696687234694>
> iex> D.add(a,b)
> #Decimal<0.33978>
> ```
>
> Please note that parsing a number with `Decimal.new/1` doesn't take
>   `Context` into consideration. It uses it only when you use some
>   `Decimal` opearation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by:

```
rounded_c1 = Decimal.round(c1, 4)
```

in which the `4` means the number of digits you may want to leave after rounding.

You can also do ceiling or floor by :

```
ceil_c1 = Decimal.round(c1, 4, :ceiling)
floor_c1 = Decimal.round(c1, 4, :floor)
```

Answer (score 0):

After falling into the rounding trap a few times, I created a tiny module just for that. Maybe it helps anyone. It uses the [Decimal](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/readme.html) library because even though people talk of alternatives in 1.6, they are not really working out for me.

```
@doc """
  Rounds a value to precision (default=2) digits after the decimal, no matter what it is
"""
def r(number, precision \\ 2)
def r(number, precision) when is_integer(number), do: number
def r(number, precision) when is_float(number), do: Decimal.from_float(number) |> Decimal.round(precision) |> Decimal.to_float()
def r(number, precision) when is_binary(number), do: Decimal.new(number) |> Decimal.round(precision) |> Decimal.to_float()
```

How to use it? Put it into a module and rename the function (`r` is not the best name). Call `MyModule.r(c1)`.
I also made it available in my views via `MyAppWeb.ex`.

If someone can explain me why `Decimal.new/1` does not accept floats, that would be great.