# How to convert Decimal so that it becomes integer?

Tags: elixir

I'm using the library Decimal.

If I have a *float* Decimal:

```
pry(4)> a1
#Decimal<179.4>
```

how can I convert to Decimal Integer or Elixir Integer? I guess I should use use round.

```
pry(5)>  Decimal.round a1, 2
#Decimal<179.40>  # <--- still float
```

But that doesn't work.

I want to be able to choose: round it up or down. That is, 179 or 180.

I'm aware of

```
Decimal.set_context(%Decimal.Context{Decimal.get_context | rounding: :floor})
```

but I don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907100/rounding-a-decimal-number-in-elixir)

Comment: @ArupRakshit that doesn't apply to my question

Answer (score 6):

[`Decimal.round/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#round/3) accepts `mode` as a third parameter. You don’t need a context here, unless you want to apply the same rounding context to everything.

```rb
dec = Decimal.from_float(3.14)
dec |> Decimal.round() |> Decimal.to_integer()
#⇒ 3
dec |> Decimal.round(0, :down) |> Decimal.to_integer()
#⇒ 3
dec |> Decimal.round(0, :up) |> Decimal.to_integer()
#⇒ 4
```

The list of available modes might be found in the documentation on [`Decimal.Context`](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.Context.html#module-rounding-algorithms).